# Is Prism-7 stable yet?

Tags: wpf, prism, prism-7

**Has anyone successfully used either the current Prism 7 (Prism.Core, Prism.Unity, and Prism.Wpf -- all at version 7.1.0.431) or the subsequent 7.2.0 pre-release versions?**

I've encountered problems with 7.1.0.431. The Prism.Unity package has a stated dependency on Unity.Abstractions 4.1.3 yet there is also an unstated one for Unity.Abstractions 3.3.1 as well. **Is this a known problem and is there a workaround?**

Using latest Nuget packages for Prism7 (Prism.Core, Prism.Unity, and Prism.Wpf -- all at version 7.1.0.431) I encountered a dependency conflict with Unity.Abstractions that wasn't stated anywhere and was presumably due to development on that package. I may have missed something but I don't think so.

That was a dead end so I backed up a few versions thinking that I could find a stable functioning version but encountered another problem with a fully qualified typename referring to System.RunTime.CompilerServices.Unsafe (a portable class library available as a Nuget package). I see many hits for this problem and binding redirects did not seem to work. Others have commented that the problem was not with Nuget but rather the packaging used to distribute the software and that I should direct inquiries to the Prism team.

I poked through the available information and some of the code seeing that a wrapper (adapter design pattern) is now being used for the container access and that a new pre-release version is available.

I'm at a crossroads at which I need to either use legacy software (Prism 5|6) or possibly rough it out with a pre-release version (it's an internal, not customer facing, app) but would like to get a feel for its stability without spending a lot of time. I'd be willing to pursue this to avoid finishing the app I'm working on then upgrading.

I am coding but this problem is not with the code per se. I can add that the problem with earlier version before 7.1.0.431 manifested itself in an exception when calling Run method of UnityBootstrapper from my App and getting the callback to a gratuitous (simple calls base method) InitializeModules method which is the last one before expected return from App invocation of UnityBootstrapper Run method. I realize that the bootstrapper has been deprecated with its function to be embedded in PrismApplication but it's apparently still there. I'd prefer moving to latest and greatest version as opposed to an earlier one.

```cs
    protected override void InitializeModules()
    {
        base.InitializeModules();
    }
```

Followed by the exception:
[image]

I'd be happy to supply more code or answer any questions and even build and debug it if I can get a little guidance regarding which version to use and assurance that others have used it successfully. Many thanks for any comments regarding Prism readiness and stability, confirmation that these are known problems or if there are workarounds.

Comment: I can't tell you whether or not it's stable but we've been using it on a large-scale project without any problems. A lot of things have changed since 6 though and it wasn't always clear documentation wise on the changes.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful information and I'd call that stable enough to take the plunge. Which version are you using? The latest or some earlier version? Maybe If it's a later version I'd expect you didn't use the deprecated UnityBootstrapper. I'm aware of the eventual need to port bootstrapper function into an App derived from PrismApplication and the other changes I'll need to make as well as the new way to access the UnityContainer.

Comment: Hi, we're using Prism 7.1.0.431 for both .Core and .Unity. As you mentioned our App is deriving from PrismApplication. Hope some of this information is useful, best of luck!